# Checkstyle instanceOf

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

Is it possible to detect type of instance with `checkstyle`?
For instance, I have code block like

```
class A {
... 

   private void method test() {
    ....
    throw new MyCustomException("Some message");
  }
}
```

In this case I want to get real instance of MyCustomException.
I know that we can use `TokenTypes.LITERAL_NEW` in custom plugin, but in this case I can get only name for an exception, but not instance type (I don't have an address for this exception type).

Comment: You need to provide more details in your example. I am confused by you can get the name, `MyCustomException`, but this is not the instance type you are looking for. What is the "correct" value you are looking for and how is it different? You looking for the full classpath of the exception or something else?

Comment: @rveach Yes, I want to get classpath for my exception/class, but in current implementation it's not possible. ```I am confused by you can get the name, MyCustomException, but this is not the instance type you are looking for``` - you can get only name, not instance.

Comment: You say instance but what you really mean is the classpath. Instance is the creation of the object in memory. You aren't emulating Java, so you aren't allocating this object.

Comment: if I know classpath I can get instance, it's obviously.

Comment: If your thinking you can instantiate the class in memory inside Checkstyle, then you should know this isn't directly supported and requires your code and Checkstyle to be on the same classpath and share classloaders. Depending on how you invoke Checkstyle, you may not get the same classloader and may not be able to instantiate even with all this information. I believe maven-checkstyle-plugin is one example where this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want is the classpath of the exception, you must emulate how Java determines the classpath from the source code.

This requires you examining the imports and package. You won't be able to fully determine this with Checkstyle since it only looks at a single file and Java actually looks at multiple folder locations, but you can get pretty close.

First look for an import with that exact class name. If there is no import, then the choices are it is coming from the `java.lang` package or the current package of the file being examined. You should build a list for any `java.lang` exceptions (if any) that you want to auto-identify. Anything else in that list would default to the file's package declaration.

There are a few checks in Checkstyle that implement this logic if you wish to see examples.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any sense in this logic. For instance, if you create an exception and you want to handle it with Checkstyle, you should add this file to some list. I guess with this approach we will get more complicated logic than profit. But anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Not all custom exceptions will be in source code you control. Throwable and Exception are defined in the JRE and Checkstyle won't have access to them. Same goes with 3rd party jars, etc. If you want to know where the class is coming from, you have to follow the imports. You can make more complicated checks to hold other file's information in memory, but Checkstyle doesn't directly support it yet.